# What does this ambiguous pronoun represent in the text of RFC 4880?

Tags: standards, definition, rfc, openpgp

What does [RFC 4880 sec 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.1) mean by "**this**"?

> The value "m" in the above formulas is derived from the session key as
> follows. First, the session key is prefixed with a one-octet algorithm
> identifier that specifies the symmetric encryption algorithm used to
> encrypt the following Symmetrically Encrypted Data Packet. Then a
> two-octet checksum is appended, which is equal to the sum of the
> preceding session key octets, not including the algorithm identifier,
> modulo 65536. **This** value is then encoded as described in PKCS#1 block
> encoding EME-PKCS1-v1_5 in Section 7.2.1 of [RFC3447] to form the "m"
> value used in the formulas above. See Section 13.1 of this document
> for notes on OpenPGP’s use of PKCS#1.

Is it the 2 octet checksum? is it the entire "one octet prefix + session key + checksum"?

Comment: I would guess its the checksum.  Can you look at some sample code, maybe here: http://www.hanewin.net/encrypt/ ?

Comment: Encrypting just the checksum doesn't sound right.  I read that as meaning the entire prefix+key+checksum

Comment: the text seems to be describing a process of accumulating elements, so I agree with TJD above that "this" would mean "the accumulated result so far", or prefix + key + checksum